# Doesn't asyncio.run() use the running event_loop if it exists? (asyncio.Queue with producer consumer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, event-loop

I'm trying to use a asyncio.Queue to implement a producer - consumer pattern.
But I found out that

1. if i create a Queue out side asyncio.run()
2. and i set the maxsize of the queue larger than amount of items that the producer can produce

It makes an error.

My code

```
class ProducerConsumer:
    """
    Producer-Consumer pattern using asyncio.Queue.
    """

    def __init__(self, generator: Generator, consumer, max_queue_size=0, adaptor=None, adaptor_input=None):
        self.generator = generator
        self.consumer = consumer
        self.adaptor = adaptor
        self.adaptor_input = adaptor_input
        self.max_queue_size = max_queue_size
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=max_queue_size)

    async def _produce(self):
        for item in self.generator:
            await self.queue.put(item)
            print(f"Produced {item}")
        await self.queue.put(None)

    async def _consume(self):
        while True:
            item = await self.queue.get()
            if self.adaptor is not None:
                item = self.adaptor(item, self.adaptor_input)
            if item is None:
                break
            self.consumer(item)
            print(f"Consumed {item}")

    async def _run(self):
        await asyncio.gather(self._produce(), self._consume())
        
    def run(self):
        asyncio.run(self._run())
            

def my_generator():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        yield i

my_consumer = print
ProducerConsumer(my_generator(), my_consumer, max_queue_size=3).run()
```

The error

```
  File "/Users/.../async_producer_consumer.py", line 22, in _produce
    await self.queue.put(item)
  File "/Users/.../.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/asyncio/queues.py", line 125, in put
    await putter
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<ProducerConsumer._produce() running at /Users/.../async_producer_consumer.py:22> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at /Users/.../.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py:769]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

I found out that this is because I have created the queue out side the asyncio.run() so two co-existing event_loops are making an issue.

My question is,

1. Doesn't the asyncio.run() use the running event_loop (which is initially made by the queue)?
2. Why Does this error not occur if i set the maxsize of queue as infinite?

Thanks a lot for reading my question.

Comment: Regarding 1 the docs say: "This function cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is running in the same thread."

Comment: Thank you for the comment! But it works fine if i set the max_size of the queue as infinite. Doesn't it mean that asyncio.run() worked fine?

Comment: I'm getting the error on Python 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9, but not on 3.10 and 3.11.

Comment: @VPfB Oh really... so you think it was a kind of bug and have been fixed in version 3.10?
P.S. Thank you for fixing the format :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find related documentation stating something like "be careful creating a Queue without an event loop", but I remember having had a similar problem with the `Queue` in my project. My answer is based mainly on the asyncio code itself.

In versions up to 3.9, the `Queue.__init__` was accepting a `loop=` parameter. If the loop was not set, it called `get_event_loop()` with the side effect of creating a new one if a current loop did not exist.

This did not go well with the `asyncio.run` which is clearly documented as "*always creates a new event loop and closes it at the end."*. The result were two loops and an error.

A workaround is to use the lower level entry point `run_until_complete` (but it does not implement a cleanup like 'run' does):

```
def run(self):
    # asyncio.run(self._run())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self._run())
```

---

Starting from 3.10, the previously deprecated `loop=` parameter was finally removed. The `Queue.__init__` was completely rewritten and the issue is fixed since then.